# Scrape td attribute rows with selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-table

I am trying to scrape with selenium a table of products.

Here is my example table:

```
<div class="article">
  <table style="width: 100%">
        <tbody><tr>
          <td class="trenner_u"></td>
          <td class="trenner_u">
            <a href="/details/12900101" class="changeable">
              <span>Product 1 </span>
            </a>
          </td>
          <td class="trenner_lu">
            11.11.1999
          </td>
          <td class="trenner_lu">
            <a title="Category Product Group" href="/grp/detailsSmallTB_iframe=true&amp;height=132&amp;width=420" class="thickbox">Group 1</a>
          </td>
          <td class="trenner_lu">
1999$
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="trenner_u"></td>
          <td class="trenner_u">
            <a href="/details/12900347" class="changeable">
              <span>Product 2 </span>
            </a>
          </td>
          <td class="trenner_lu">
            1.12.1944
          </td>
          <td class="trenner_lu">
            <a title="Category Product Group" href="/grp/detailsSmallTB_iframe=true&amp;height=132&amp;width=420" class="thickbox">Group 2</a>
          </td>
          <td class="trenner_lu">
1234$
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="trenner_u"></td>
          <td class="trenner_u">
            <a href="/details/12908635" class="changeable">
                <img class="positionable" src="/ImageImage/12908635" alt="" style="width: 100px; opacity: 0.9;">  
              <span>Product 1 </span>
  <img src="/Content/images/icons/photo.png" alt="Foto">
            </a>
          </td>
          <td class="trenner_lu">
            05.12.1950
          </td>
          <td class="trenner_lu">
                        <a title="Category Product Group" href="/grp/detailsSmallTB_iframe=true&amp;height=132&amp;width=420" class="thickbox">Group 2</a>
,<a title="Category Product Group" href="/grp/detailsSmallTB_iframe=true&amp;height=132&amp;width=420" class="thickbox">Group 4</a>

          </td>
          <td class="trenner_lu">
131282$
          </td>
        </tr>
        
  </tbody></table>
</div>
```

I tried to scrape each element with:

```
    List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"home\"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a"));
    List<WebElement> prodNames = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"home\"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a"));
    List<WebElement> group = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"home\"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/a"));
```

However, as you can see one of my `td` elements has two links inside, therefore my WebElement list has not the same length and it is extremely hard to merge together.

My desired list output should look like that:

```
[Product 1, 11.11.1999, Group 1, 1999$], [Product 2, 1.12.1944,Group 2, 1234$], [Product 1, 05.12.1950, Group 2 Group 2, 131282$]
```

Any suggestion how to scrape such a table much more efficient?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1):

Think about everything you interact with as of objects:

```
class Table {
    private static final String TABLE_CELL = "//table/tbody/tr[%d]/td[%d]";

    public String getTableCellText(int row, int col) {
        WebElement cell = driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format(TABLE_CELL, row, col)));
        return cell.getText();
    }
}
```

You can use it as you see fit:

```
    Table t = new Table();
    System.out.println(t.getTableCellText(3, 5)); // prints 131282$
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably iterate through each row to make it clearer as to what you are doing in python it would be:

```
rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"home\"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr")
for row in rows:
    cells = row.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//td")
    product_name = cells[1].text
    ... etc ...
```